# Compilation error in this code

Tags: java, android

Compilation error in this code , how can I fix this java code?

anyone know how to fix this? and the `label284;` is giving some problem.

Pastebin : http://pastebin.com/gWKwnqg5

Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM1St.png

```
 private List<int[]> getDataByAverage()
  {
    int i = this.money;
    Object localObject1 = new ArrayList();
    if (this.num != 1)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < this.num; j++)
        ((List)localObject1).add(new int[2]);
      i /= this.num;
      j = 0;
      int k = 0;
      while (k < this.num)
      {
        Object localObject2;
        if (k + 1 != this.num)
        {
          int n;
          if (10.0D * Math.random() <= 5.0D)
            n = 0;
          else
            n = 1;
          int m = (int)(Math.round(Math.random() * i) / 2L);
          localObject2 = (int[])((List)localObject1).get(k);
          if (n == 0)
            m = i - m;
          else
            m = i + m;
          localObject2[0] = m;
          j += ((int[])localObject1.get(k))[0];
        }
        else
        {
          localObject2 = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(this.money));
          BigDecimal localBigDecimal = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(j));
          ((int[])localObject1.get(k))[0] = ((BigDecimal)localObject2).subtract(localBigDecimal).intValue();
        }
        if (((int[])localObject1.get(k))[0] >= 0)
        {
          k++;
          continue;
        }
        localObject1 = getDataByAverage();
        break label284;
      }
      localObject1 = localObject1;
    }
    else
    {
      int[] arrayOfInt = new int[2];
      arrayOfInt[0] = this.money;
      ((List)localObject1).add(arrayOfInt);
      localObject1 = localObject1;
    }
    label284: return (List<int[]>)(List<int[]>)localObject1;
  }
```

Comment: It helps a lot if you tell us what the error is.

Comment: here's the image : http://i.imgur.com/OwbdR.png

Comment: ArrayList doesn't mean it's list of arrays, it means that it is a list backed by array. why ain't your localObejct1 of type List<Integer[]>?

Comment: And also break is not goto command!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess labeled break is used to get out of multiple for or while loops. And you will have to declare the label above where you are using it.
you can check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

You will have to move `label284:` before it is used.

Might well be a method to declare a label which i am not aware of

**Edit**: Here's the method, put braces across the whole   `if (this.num != 1) else { }` routine. Then define `label284:` before it. 
Apparently the break label will goto end of statement. For more details check [here](http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/java_break_to_label_tatement.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 private List<int[]> getDataByAverage()
    {
        int i = this.money;
        Object localObject1 = new ArrayList();
        if (this.num != 1)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.num; j++)
                ((List)localObject1).add(new int[2]);
            i /= this.num;
            j = 0;
            int k = 0;
            Object localObject2;
                if (k + 1 != this.num)
                {
                    int n;
                    if (10.0D * Math.random() <= 5.0D)
                        n = 0;
                    else
                        n = 1;
                    int m = (int)(Math.round(Math.random() * i) / 2L);
                    localObject2 = (int[])((List)localObject1).get(k);
                    if (n == 0)
                        m = i - m;
                    else
                        m = i + m;
                    localObject2= m;
                    j += ((int[])((List<int[]>) localObject1).get(k))[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    localObject2 = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(this.money));
                    BigDecimal localBigDecimal = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(j));
                    ((int[])((List<int[]>) localObject1).get(k))[0] = ((BigDecimal)localObject2).subtract(localBigDecimal).intValue();
                }
                if (((int[])((List<int[]>) localObject1).get(k))[0] >= 0)
                {
                    k++;

                }
                localObject1 = getDataByAverage();

            localObject1 = localObject1;
        }
        else
        {
            int[] arrayOfInt = new int[2];
            arrayOfInt[0] = this.money;
            ((List)localObject1).add(arrayOfInt);
            localObject1 = localObject1;
        }
        return (List<int[]>)(List<int[]>)localObject1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `localObject1` as a `List` instead of an `Object`.  That should fix this error.